# Generic callbacks from C# Tasks

Tags: c#, callback, task-parallel-library, async-await

What is the recommended way to call generic callbacks from an `async Task`? For example, progress, exception handling and completion (but could be other states).

The following code shows one way to implement it, but feels like there should be a cleaner way to handle this. (FWIW I've seen plenty of examples using `ContinueWith` as a completion callback, but this doesn't really deal with other cases like progress and exception handling).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testcode
{
    class TestApp
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            AsyncCallbackTest test = new AsyncCallbackTest();
            test.RunTest();
        }
    }

    interface ICallback
    {
        void onProgress(String status);
        void onCompleted();
        void onFaulted(Exception e);
    }

    class AsyncCallbackTest : ICallback
    {

        public void RunTest()
        {
            //run task in background
            Task task = new Task(new Action<Object>(ExampleTask), this);
            task.Start();

            //do something else here
            //...

            //wait for task completion
            task.Wait();
        }

        public void onProgress(string status)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(status);
        }

        public void onCompleted()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
        }

        public void onFaulted(Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
        }

        private void ExampleTask(object ocb)
        {
            ICallback callback = ocb as ICallback;

            //do some work
            try
            {
                DoSomething(callback);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //how to pass exceptions/errors?
                callback.onFaulted(e);
            }
        }

        //example long-running task
        private void DoSomething(ICallback callback)
        {
            callback.onProgress("Starting");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            callback.onProgress("Step 1 complete");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            callback.onProgress("Step 2 complete");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            callback.onCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception handling is pretty easy with the new async/await. When you await a task, any unhandled exception thrown within it is propagated to the awaiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completion and exception handling is very easy with `async`-`await`. Progress handling is exactly what the `IProgress` interface is for.

So the signature of your method would be something like:

```
public Task DoSomething(IProgress<string> progress = null);
```

And you would call it like this:

```
try
{
    await DoSomething(new Progress<string>(status => Console.WriteLine(status)));
    Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
}
```

If you can't use C# 5.0, then you could use `ContinueWith()` instead of `await` and you would have to write your own `IProgress` and `Progress`:

```
DoSomething(new Progress<string>(status => Console.WriteLine(status)))
    .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + t.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `IProgress<T>` interface, or its `Progress<T>` [implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can find a blog post describing its usage [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx), but it is basically like using callbacks.

Using the [Reactive Extensions](https://rx.codeplex.com/) like @Kirill Shlenskiy suggested can be an option too, but I think adding support for that to an existing method using Tasks might not be the easiest solution.